# Displaying ManyToManyField in Django Detail Generic View

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In my Django project I have two models - Program and Cycle - which are linkedin by a ManyToMany Relationship, so that one program can have many cycles and at the same time cycles can be part of many different programs.

From a Generic List View, the user can select one program and access the Detail View of that programs, where I am supposed to show all the cycles included in the selected program.

views.py

```
class AllProgramsView (generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'programs/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'programs_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Program.objects.all()


class ProgramDetailView (generic.DetailView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'programs/program.html'
```

in models.py

```
class Cycle(models.Model):
    cycle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    cycle_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    steps = models.ManyToManyField(Step)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cycle_name + "  --  " + self.cycle_description

class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cycles = models.ManyToManyField(Cycle)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default="False")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('programs:program', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_name
```

In the html template, program.html

```
<div class="bg-white">
  <div class="container text-center text-muted">
    <div class="row">
    {% if cycle %}
          {% for cycle in program %}
         <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
         <div class="card">
           <p><h5>{{ cycles.cycle_name }}</h5></p>
           <p class="card-text">{{ cycles.cycle_description }}</p>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary">Modify it</a>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <div class="bg-white">
         <p>No Cycles Found</p>
       </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that no cycles get displayed in the detail page, even though I have programs with cycles saved in the db so they should display. 
Is there any error in the code?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This can't possibly be real code. Your ProgramDetailView would immediately throw a NameError for `self`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If by real code you mean that this is not the right code to be used, then you may be right: I'm just starting out with Django and building my knowledge step by step. This code is what I came up with after reading all the documentation I could retrieve. It does produce errors, so the purpose of posting it on here is to see if someone more knowledgeable than me can help. What I am trying to achieve is a page where people can see all the cycles contained into a program. Do you happen to have any suggestion?

Comment: But you said "the issue is that no cycles get displayed in the detail page". That means the page is at least getting displayed, which *could not possibly happen* with the code you have posted. If you want us to help you, you need to post the actual code you are using. Or, describe the actual issue you are having, which in this case would be "the code is throwing a NameError when I start the server".

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've been working on this code for hours and before the latest change I've made to ProgramDetailView, I didn't get errors yet the detail page was still lacking the list of cycles. Then I tried fixing by modifying the view and came up with this code you're seeing, which is giving me 'TypeError: 'property' object not iterable'. I can get back to the previous code if that is useful for fixing the cycles not showing issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ProgramDetailView (generic.DetailView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'programs/program.html'
    context_object_name = 'sp'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cycles'] = self.get_object().cycles.all()
        return super(ProgramDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

or

---

```
class ProgramDetailView (generic.DetailView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'programs/program.html'
    context_object_name = 'sp'
    slug_field = 'id'
```

html

```
<div class="bg-white">
  <div class="container text-center text-muted">
    <div class="row">
    {% if sp %}
       {% for cycle in sp.cycles.all %}
         <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
         <div class="card">
           <p><h5>{{ cycles.cycle_name }}</h5></p>
           <p class="card-text">{{ cycles.cycle_description }}</p>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary">Modify it</a>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <div class="bg-white">
         <p>No Cycles Found</p>
       </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's not really any need to do this in the view at all; it can be done directly in the template. But since OP hasn't even shown working code, it's hard to know where her real problem is.

Comment: you are right.this's what he's most likely to achieve

Comment: @Ykh okay I'll try your solution, thank you for posting. Just in case it wasn't clear from the question, what I am trying to achieve is a page where people can see all the cycles contained into a program.

Comment: @Ykh I've replaced my code with yours but I now get a NoReverseMatch Error. I've edited my question with the code version who wasn't getting any errors but still didn't display the cycles list.

Comment: add     `context_object_name = 'sp' slug_field = 'id'` to your DetailView

Comment: I did, but if I add those I get the NoReverseMatch error. Is there anything else that I should add/change?

Comment: post your error log 、url.py and programs/index.html